# Extern variable C

Tags: c

the error generate is : Segmentation fault

Myheader.h

```
#ifndef datest
#define datest
struct date{
    char c;
    FILE* gestor;
};

typedef struct date dateStruct;
extern dateStruct date_Struct;

void loadLine();
#endif
```

myMain.c

```
#include "myheader.h"
...

dateStruct date_Struct;

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
        date_Struct.gestor = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        loadLine();
}
```

MyHeader.c

```
#include "myheader.h"

void loadLine(){
    char* TEXT;
    fscanf(date_Struct.gestor, "%s\n", TEXT);  //ERROR! why?
    ...

}
```

I can't solve this , i need declare the extern var in myheader.c too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The segmentation fault might occur because the file wasn't opened successfully and `date_Struct.gestor` is a NULL pointer.

Check the return value from `fopen()` — **always!**  It may fail, and if you use the null pointer, you get segmentation faults.

The other problem is with `TEXT` (don't use all-caps for variables; use lower-case or camel-case and reserve all-caps for macros).

The pointer TEXT does not point anywhere; it is not initialized.  When you read using it, all hell breaks loose.  (The pointer might point anywhere; in the worst case scenario, it points to somewhere valid but unexpected, your `fscanf()` 'works', but you trample over some data and you've no idea how it got corrupted.  A segmentation fault is fortunate; it tells you that something was clearly wrong.)  This is more plausibly your problem.

```
void loadLine()
{
     char TEXT[4096];
     if (fscanf(date_Struct.gestore, "%s\n", TEXT) != 1)
         ...process error...
```

Check the return value from `fscanf()` too; it tells you whether it worked as you expected or not.  Get used to checking for error returns.  It's always necessary to know how to handle errors, and quite a lot of code is usually devoted to doing so.

Answer (score 4):

```
fscanf(date_Struct.gestor, "%s\n", TEXT);  //ERROR! why?
```

TEXT is uninitialized; it's most probably pointing to garbage, so your program segfaults when trying to write to it.

You need to allocate memory for TEXT beforehand, either in the stack or using `malloc()` (or its friends).

Answer (score 1):

A "Segmentation Fault", or segfault as it's more commonly called, occurs when you try to access something that you cannot. In your case on the line `fscanf(date_Struct.gestor, "%s\n", TEXT);` you use the `TEXT` variable without initializing it.

You need to first allocate some memory for the `TEXT` variable.